# javascript init not launching

Tags: javascript

Here's a part of the code that I have, why isn't the init function called? I am trying to use the javascript here http://www.openjs.com/scripts/ui/calendar/

```
  <link href="http://www.openjs.com/scripts/ui/calendar/calendar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><script type="text/javascript"> 
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="http://www.openjs.com/scripts/ui/calendar/calendar.js"></SCRIPT>
    <script language="javascript">
        function init() {


calendar.set("DOB");
```

}

```
    </script>

<input name="DOB" id="DOB" value="Client's Date of Birth"/>
```

Comment: have you make sure the input element is ready? when calendar.set is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only defining the `init` function but not calling it.

Try to add a call to that function when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){ init(); }
</script>
```

OR:

```
<body onload="init()">...
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to register init(){..} to DOM ready event. They do it in

```
<script src="http://www.openjs.com/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

common.js

```
function siteInit() {
    if(typeof window.init == "function") init();
```

Answer (score 1):

On the example website, it has this near the closing  tag:

```
<script src="http://www.openjs.com/js/jsl.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://www.openjs.com/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Adding this to your page before the closing  tag should launch the calendar.